# manage.py runserver python not found

Tags: python, django, manage.py, django-runserver

I'm trying to learn django and I'm almost completely new to python, I'm using pycharm btw.
My problem is that when i try to type

```
python manage.py runserver
```

in the PyCharm terminal it just tells me that Python was not found.

I have already tried to reinstall python and add it to system variables.

Comment: Could you post exactly which error it shows and OS you are using

Comment: In Linux or Mac terminal type ```which python``` or ```which python3``` and do ```find / -name python``` and ```find / -name python3```, and specify in your Pycharm once you know you can call python on some scripts.

Comment: More information is always appreciated, to give you the correct commands, and to analyze the problem based on facts. Did you try to run the command from the terminal / PowerShell directly? Are you sure that is a problem with PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure your PyCharm path to show where is interpreter of Python on your PC.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: I already had my interpreter working fine so it didn't work.